# SQL request times out when IF EXISTS evaluates to true

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm sending an SQL query to my database. It times out if it's true, but runs perfectly if it's false. First, the SQL code:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    --Set error variables
    SELECT
    @ErrorPosition = 10,
    @CustomErrorMessage = 'Error 1';

    IF EXISTS(SELECT a.CustID 
    FROM Logins a 
    LEFT JOIN Addrs b ON a.CustID = b.CustID 
    WHERE a.User = @username AND b.EMail = @email) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'success' 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 'failure' 
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    EXECUTE dbo.LogError @ErrorModule, @ErrorPosition, @CustomErrorMessage
END CATCH
```

Note that this actually executes fine whether true or false, when I manually run it from SQL server.

Now, the code that evaluates FALSE (and works):

```
$sql = "EXEC Test @username='test_user',@email='wrong@example.com'";
$exec = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

$result = odbc_result($exec,1);

echo $result;
```

This code runs fine, and outputs 'failure' (the correct email is email@website.com).
Now the code that evaluates to TRUE:

```
$sql = "EXEC Test @username='test_user',@email='email@website.com'";
$exec = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

$result = odbc_result($exec,1);

echo $result;
```

This times out.

No errors are logged either by PHP or SQL. Similar IF EXISTS statements can be run from PHP with no errors.

Comment: Question: If you swap the `EXEC` statements true/false, does it still fail on true?

Comment: I think you should include the full relevant PHP code here.

Comment: You may use only    IF() in sql query

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean IF NOT EXISTS(...) BEGIN SELECT 'Success' END ELSE BEGIN SELECT 'Failure' END? Also, that is the full relevant PHP code. The only bit I've omitted is the database connection parameters, which do work.

Comment: Also change it to INNER JOIN - because of WHERE contents.

Comment: @PradyutManna That's not true. I have successfully used IF EXISTS() before.

Comment: @TimBiegelsen if I use IF NOT EXISTS, it times out when it evaluates to false (i.e. the IF EXISTS would be true).

Comment: Try to comment out different parts of your code and check how it works. Also there is a chance that your `dbo.LogError ` does now work.

Comment: How long does the query take to run in management studio?  Is it longer than your timeout window on your connection?  Have you looked at the Execution plan the query uses, it's possible a simple index could make a big difference.

Comment: Problem has been solved now - only certain SQL users were timing out, including the one that PHP used. Restarting SQL server fixed the issue.